# CPU spikes higher as time progresses, while doing the same work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have an ASP.NET Core project, that consists of a server and a client project. The server uses ASP.NET Core 6.0.9 and the client is an ASP.NET Core WebAssembly project, using the same runtime.

In the `Startup.cs` class of the server, I've registered [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), for scheduling background jobs:

```
//quartz background jobs
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    q.UseJobFactory<IntegrationJobFactory>();

    foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        var calendarInterval = (CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder)job.GetProperty(nameof(IBackgroundJob.CalendarInterval))?.GetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(job));
        q.AddJob(job, configure: x => x.WithIdentity(job.Name));

        q.AddTrigger(x => x
            .ForJob(job.Name)
            .StartNow()
            .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(calendarInterval));
        
    }
});
```

I've used some reflection to load the jobs dynamically. (`jobs` is just a list of types that implement the `IJob` interface.)

This all works perfectly fine. The job starts reliably and does all its work as it should. All it does is fetch some data from one API, do some minor calculations and use another API to write the results to an external server. It also logs some stuff in a MySQL database - which is hosted on the same server - along the way.

I use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) for the logging, with this configuration:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.MariaDB(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), tableName: $"{nameof(BackgroundJob)}_Logs", autoCreateTable: true, useBulkInsert: true, 
                                options: new Serilog.Sinks.MariaDB.MariaDBSinkOptions() { LogRecordsExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7), TimestampInUtc = true })
            .CreateLogger();
```

I use docker-compose and the [https-portal](https://github.com/SteveLTN/https-portal) for hosting the app and the database.

Now, the problem:
When monitoring my server, I noticed, that the CPU usage increases with every execution of the job.

[image: Cpu usage over time]

The big spikes are when I've re-deployed the app. As you can see, the CPU spikes higher and higher with every execution, then returns to normal, idle level before spiking even higher with the next execution. Here's a more zoomed in visualization:

[image: Cpu usage over time (zoomed)]

The job is doing pretty much the same work every run. Sure, there might be some minor increase in load every 10th execution or so, but then why does the CPU usage drop so drastically after a rebuild? RAM usage stays at about 40% and doesn't change.

Just to be clear, this doesn't happen because the job has more work with time progressing. I can confirm this because the job ran for a long time with the same exact workload, and still the spikes increased.

If this happened to the memory, then I'd say it's some kind of memory leak, but how can this happen to the CPU?

The fact that only the spikes increase, while the idle usage stays the same, makes me wonder if this is some sort of issue with the Quartz.Net framework?

Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this?

Comment: Increasing memory pressure? Do you need to call Dispose() on something like connections or jobs?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without knowing more about your code, or at least having some kind of [mre].

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I just realized, that the logging might have something to do with it. I've updated my question to include the Serilog configuration. As of now, the table contains ~380'000 rows.

Comment: If you are wondering about CPU usage, use a performance profiler to see what it is actually doing.  If you suspect a memory leak, use a memory profiler. There could be multiple reasons, and there is not much point in guessing.

Comment: Each top of an hour, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%' and you will probably recognize that some numbers are growing.  Likely suspects, aborted_connects, threads_connected.  If threads connected are growing, it is likely someone forgot the CLOSE of your CONNECT, PROCESS, CLOSE sequence recommended for each client connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days of observing the cpu usage, it seems like I solved the issue.

It had nothing to do with Quartz.Net, but with the logging.

I use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) for the logging, with a MariaDB database as storage for the logs. Every run logs about 700 rows, which meant that the table quickly grew to a substantial size. Since the database runs on the same server, the CPU increase probably doesn't have anything to do with my application at all.

I fixed this by decreasing the `LogRecordsExpiration` parameter from 7 to 2 days. After clearing the table, the CPU increase is still there, but much smaller, and it seems to flatten out after those 2 days.